# How do I open a file to read in a C# restful service?

Tags: c#, streamreader, wcf-rest

I get a

> 400 Bad Request error

...whenever I try to **open a file**, but I can write to it just fine.

I've tried using new StreamReader, File.OpenRead(path), etc, and I always get the same error. Commenting out the code related to the streamreader allows me to write the username to the file.

```
 public bool isValidUsername(string username)
        {
            string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("users.txt");
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
            string nextLine = sr.ReadLine();

                while (nextLine != null)
                {
                    if (string.Compare(nextLine, username) == 0)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    nextLine = sr.ReadLine();
                }


            File.AppendAllText(path, username + "\n");
                return true;
        }
```

I am trying to read a file that contains usernames to make sure that the given username hasn't already been taken, and if it isn't I want to add that username to the text file. I know the path is correct because I can write to it using the AppendAllText line.

Comment: 400 is a bad request, it might be with the way you are calling the method. Try running it in debugging mode with a breakpoint and step through it? See if it reaches the right endpoint, and if the read file method is being called. Adding on, if something broke in your code, you would have seen a `500 Internal Server Error` or similar

Comment: [See this post for possible troubleshooting of a 400 error](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-fix-a-400-bad-request-error-2617988)

Comment: Should you be using a `using() { }` with your `StreamReader` (that or call `Close()`).  It might explain subsequent read failures

Comment: And don’t be afraid to throw that streamreader in a using block.